# Unregister WordPress plugin widget from theme

Tags: wordpress, widget

Question about WordPress theme - plugins interaction.
Can i unregister widget that was added by plugin using theme functions.php file?
Tried to unregister it using sample code, but it didn't work for me:

```
function remove_some_widget() {
    unregister_widget('some_plugin_widget');
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_some_widget' );
```

Comment: What did you put in `some_plugin_widget` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to pass in `unregister_widget` function is the name of a class that extends, so, pass the appropriate class name. Here is an example of [unregister_widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget) to Unregister all widgets

```
 function unregister_default_widgets() {
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Pages');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Calendar');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Archives');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Links');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Meta');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Search');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Text');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Categories');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Posts');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Comments');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_RSS');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud');
     unregister_widget('WP_Nav_Menu_Widget');
     unregister_widget('Twenty_Eleven_Ephemera_Widget');
 }
 add_action('widgets_init', 'unregister_default_widgets', 11);
```

Comment: For some unknown reason this doesn't work for me...Widgets are in the same place as usual.

Comment: I had this headache for a little while tonight. Eventually I found that setting the priority to 100 or more was causing the non-removal of widgets. This is the priority when Wordpress triggers `WP_Widget_Factory–>_register_widgets`. Not sure of the whys/hows/if it's a bug or not, but to get it working just ensure your `add_action` priority is <= 99